# Searching on tags works, but sorting on type and status doesn't

Tags: bug, search

I just noticed that my search `[code-review] is:q closed:no` failed over to the maintenance page.
I repeated the search omitting the `is:q closed:no` and it worked like a charm.

Is this known behaviour, due to the way search is implemented or a bug?

[image]

Comment: Seems there's unstable behavior. Certainly not known behavior. Got 0 results once with an abnormally long wait time, offline for maintenance once.

Comment: Note that the search query should return at least some results (currently at least [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47021754/7296893), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46541967/7296893), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44452555/7296893) and more). If you get 0 results on the search, that's still a bug

Comment: This is a network-wide issue.

Comment: For reference, this is the issue on Meta.SE: [Recent problems with searching (no results or getting maintenance page)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317166/289905).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Xufox, also an answer there from Nick. So a confirmed bug.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by [Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/4642212) in the comments there is also a question on MSE, that has this answer by [Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver):

> We had a cluster member register a voltage spike on the 10G NIC this
>   morning which caused it to drop from the cluster ungracefully, causing
>   a rapid reallocation and queue exhaustion which caused all other
>   errors downstream (thread_pool.search.queue_size, specifically).
>
> I am still working on cluster stability now, we'll need a few more
>   node moves to tweak settings to prevent it from recurring. I don't
>   have an ETA at the moment, but will post here if we can figure that
>   out (ES is a bit erratic on recovery times with our workload).

[Nick Craver on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317166)