# Is there an issue with the Stack Overflow question list today?

Tags: discussion, bug, questions, asking-questions

I found a strange issue on Stack Overflow.

In the last 1 hour, four questions are repeated within a few minutes of time.

Question links are

> First question (3 mins difference) asked by [amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403315/amir)

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947957/migrating-to-andriodx* (question is deleted now)
- *[Migrating to AndriodX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947956/migrating-to-andriodx)*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947959/migrating-to-andriodx* (question is deleted now)

> Second question (less than 1 mins difference) asked by [ir2pid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838355/ir2pid)

- *[Kotlin Type mismatch, required: x found: x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948620/kotlin-type-mismatch-required-x-found-x)*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948660/kotlin-type-mismatch-required-x-found-x* (question is deleted now)

> Third question (less than 1 mins difference) asked by [Dimaslviv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3816129/dimaslviv)

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947761/xirsys-turn-servers-dont-work-with-android-webrtc* (question is deleted now)
- *[xirsys turn servers don't work with Android WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947823/xirsys-turn-servers-dont-work-with-android-webrtc)*

**UPDATE**

> fourth question (less than 1 mins difference) asked by [kanudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474961/kanudo)

- *[Retrofit does not deliver Java Object as POST parameters on PHP backend from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949233/retrofit-does-not-deliver-the-post-parameters-on-php-backend-from-android)*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949199/retrofit-does-not-deliver-the-post-parameters-on-php-backend-from-android* (question is deleted now)

Has anyone noticed this issue or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: since they are deleted, I can't see... but they don't seem to be the same question, and it seems like it is voluntarily removed by author, so I would guess someone making a mistake and fixing it. Are they all from the same OPs? (I mean are the deleted copies of the questions all from the same OP as the non-deleted copy?)

Comment: @Patrice yes.. They are indeed asked by the original asker

Comment: People tend to reask their question if they feel their first post did not get enough attention or did not receive an answer (although this is counterproductive and runs afoul of site rules). Close as dupe if you come across this

Comment: @SurajRao yes i agree with u and also seen these type of  situation  where people re-ask their question but in this case the time gap between question are just few mins (<5mins) that's why i raised question in  meta

Comment: Something's broken here... I've done a search for `deleted:1 is:q` and around the same time frame, there's quite a lot more of this occurring... even the same post with the same title (which shouldn't be allowed) by one OP 8 times in a minute... It's expected to happen but the frequency it has around a certain time period looks out of place.

Comment: This is part of the new "_express question ban_" feature introduced for New Contributors.

Comment: Relevant comment from Amir: "StackOverflow had an error and now I see it duplicated".  So yes.  Some of these users might end up with a question ban, ouch.

Comment: Here we are, being all welcoming and what not, and then the platform decides "nah, I don't like it" on its own.

Comment: Probably related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375671/searching-on-tags-works-but-sorting-on-type-and-status-doesnt and its related MSE topic

Comment: SO is just mimicking how Github was behaving yesterday, it's the new hip way of doing websites.

Comment: RIP, ran into this experience as well. Mod flagged [posts by this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8130727/theordinarygeek?tab=questions&sort=newest), as they had a bunch of dupes as well.

Comment: @JonClements that sound like the system isn't properly handling submissions, failing in the front-end for unspecified causes but letting it go through in the backend.

Comment: @Braiam There's supposed to be a hard limit of 6 questions per 24 hour period per user on SO which I'm fairly sure is checked at the back-end... it's almost like the back-end checks just aren't working - duplicate titles - hard limits etc...

Comment: @JonClements Maybe someone on Twitter complained about the limit :-P

Comment: @Bart I agree. It’s not a big, it’s a feature!

Comment: I had an issue yeserday where when asking a question the UI froze up when I pressed "post". I ended up closing the browser and cut and pasting it a couple of times. I thought at the time I was worried that it might add duplicates but when it eventually posted, I only had one question. I chalked it up to a short term bork and maybe network issues, but maybe it was this problem?

Comment: @JonClements I've had an issue recently (on SFF not SO) where if I pressed "Save Edit" whilst it was submitting it still (i.e. the progress dots) it would stack the edit and submit them all (see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/197196/revisions) for example. Could be users pressing ask a few times in a similar manner.